# How to create an alias topic pointing to a queue in IBM Websphere MQ?

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq, mqtt, telemetry

I'm trying to send messages between an application using WebSphere MQ queues, and a nodeJS application using the Websphere MQ topics via the MQTT protocol.

I know we can create an alias queue :

- pointing to a topic (in that case, the application listen to new publications via an alias queue),
- pointing to another queue.

Now, I want the opposite procedure:

**How can I create an alias topic pointing to a queue ?**
In that case, the nodeJS applicaton would be able to listen to the incoming messages via the alias topic from the other application which pushes messages on the original queue.

Configuration :

- WebSphere v7.5
- Node v5.5.0
- Protocol MQTT v3

Comment: Can you please update your question with more details on scenario? How an alias topic pointing to a queue helps your case?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found myself the answer.

To resolve it, I had to create a subscription, specifying the topic source and the queue destination. To do it, in the IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer :

- Go in the navigator -> IBM WebSphereMQ -> Queue Managers -> Select your queue -> Subscriptions -> New -> Subscription
- Enter the name of your subscription -> click "Next"
- Enter/Select the default attribute "SYSTEM.DEFAULT.SUB"
- Enter the name of the topic (you can select it among the existing in the button on the right)
- Enter the name of the existing queue destination
- Click "Terminate"

That's it ! There were the minimal prerequisites to make it, but you can specify other options.
You can check the properties of subscription on the documentation via this link :
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_properties_subs.htm

**Note : The instructions' words can be slightly different because I translated the functionnalities of the Websphere MQ software from french to english to answer this post.**

(Edit) Explanation :

My NodeJS application has to communicate both ways (publish/receive) with the other app.
As @Shashi said in the comments, MQTT protocol basically works only with Publish/Subscribe model.
However, it is able to communicates with a queue **thanks to the "Subscription" functionnality of IBM WebSphere MQ software** as I explain earlier.

Indeed, according to what I understand, the "Subscription" functionnality is a kind of "bridge" *linking/converting* a topic (for the NodeJS) to a destination queue (for the app).

It is the opposite of what an AliasQueue can be for a Topic in IBM Websphere MQ :

> "An alias name can also resolve to a topic. If an application currently puts messages onto a queue, it can be made to publish to a topic by making the queue name an alias for the topic. No change to the application code is necessary." ([from the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q003120_.htm))

Comment: Is your NodeJS application publishing messages or receiving messages? As far as I know MQTT protocol works only for Publish/Subscribe model, not queue yet. So wondering how NodeJS application will be able to receive messages from a queue.